# Подключение Perfect Money в YII2 advanced

Tags: php, yii2

Я только начал изучать *YII2*. Есть задача подключить прием платежей через *Perfect Money*.

Есть компонент для этого - [yii2-perfect-money](https://github.com/yii-dream-team/yii2-perfect-money). Есть мануал, но не раскрыты некоторые моменты.

Я поставил этот компонент через компосер (использую *vagrant - scotch*), добавил в конфиг конфиг компонента.

Что необходимо сделать сразу? Подтягивается все в автомате, либо нужно создавать контроллер, либо копировать контроллер из папки модуля - `src`?

Может, более расширенный мануал по аналогичному модулю кто подскажет.

Answer (score 1):

Никакого расширенного мануала нет. А тебе советую учить английский и читать [документацию компонента](https://github.com/yii-dream-team/yii2-perfect-money/blob/master/README.md)